# Using FsCheck I get different results on tests, once 100% passed and the other time error

Tags: testing, f#, generator, fscheck

I created a generator to generate lists of int with the same lenght and to test the property of zip and unzip.
Running the test I get once in a while the error

> Error: System.ArgumentException: list2 is 1 element shorter than list1

but it shouldn't happen because of my generator.

I got three times the test 100% passed and then the error above. Why?
It seems my generator is not working properly.

```
let samelength (x, y) = 
    List.length x = List.length y

let arbMyGen2 = Arb.filter samelength Arb.from<int list * int list> 

type MyGenZ =
    static member genZip() = 
       {
        new Arbitrary<int list * int list>() with
            override x.Generator = arbMyGen2 |> Arb.toGen
            override x.Shrinker t = Seq.empty
    }

let _ = Arb.register<MyGenZ>()

let pro_zip (xs: int list, ys: int list) = 
   (xs, ys) = List.unzip(List.zip xs ys)
   |> Prop.collect (List.length xs = List.length ys)

do Check.Quick pro_zip
```

Comment: Do it work if you specify your property using `Prop.forAll`? `let pro_zip = Prop.forAll MyGenZ.genZip() (xs : int list, ys: int list) ...`

Comment: Not sure if this is what you thought `let pro_zip  = 
    Prop.forAll MyGenZ.genZip() (xs: int list, ys: int list) = List.unzip(List.zip xs ys)` but I get the error on `MyGenZ.genZip()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code, as written, works for me. So I'm not sure what exactly is wrong, but I can give you a few helpful (hopefully!) hints.

In the first instance, try not using the registrating mechanism, but instead using `Prop.forAll`, as follows:

```
let pro_zip  = 
   Prop.forAll arbMyGen2 (fun (xs,ys) ->
        (xs, ys) = List.unzip(List.zip xs ys)
        |> Prop.collect (List.length xs))

do Check.Quick pro_zip
```

Note I've also changed your `Prop.collect` call to collect the length of the list(s), which gives somewhat more interesting output. In fact your property already checks that the lists are the same length (albeit implicitly) so the test will fail with a counterexample if they are not.

`Arb.filter` transforms an existing `Arbitrary` (i.e. generator *and* filter) to a new `Arbitrary`. In other words, `arbMyGen2` has a shrinking function that'll work (i.e. only returns smaller pairs of lists that are of equal length), while in `genZip()` you throw the shrinker away. It would be fine to simply write

```
type MyGenZ =
    static member genZip() = arbMyGen2
```

instead.

Comment: What’s the difference between register a generator than using Prop.forAll? When should I use the first method and when the second?

About my code, I get an error during test about the length of lists. This happens if I don’t execute the code all together in F# Interactive (I use Monodevelop), if I execute first the code without the quick check and the I execute it I get this error. Maybe it’s my computer, I don’t know.

Comment: Prop.forAll is preferred because it is clearer (you can tell from the property which Arbitrary instance is being used) and it is not prone to the same problems `Arb.register` is, as you've just experienced. Especially in F# Interactive I'd try to avoid the register method because every time you execute a bit of code it gets compiled to its own (compiler generated) module etc, which can have weird side-effects. I think something like that is the cause of your problem.